# Search page and URL for keyword

Tags: javascript

I would like to check the page for the word "testing", also I would like to check the URL. So for example if you're on site.com/tester that's fine, but if you're on site.com/testing javascript would know. Would you do this with document hostname?

Real world example: Pretty much I just want to create a greasemonkey script to search a page to search a page/url for a username "exgirlfriend"  and if "exgirlfriend" is found anywhere on the page document.body.innerHTML= ''

How would I do this?

Comment: `var ex = document.body.innerHTML.match(/exgirlfriend/);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that searches both the innerHTML and the URL for your word.

```
init();

function init()
{
    searchWord("exgirlfriend");  
}

function searchWord(word)
{
   var pageResults = document.body.innerHTML.match(word);  
   var urlResults = window.location.href.match(word);
   if(pageResults || urlResults)
   {
       alert("word found");    
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vfbzc/